# Circular permutation with identical objects

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

> Six people sit at a circular table. Three men and three women. What is the probability that all girls sit together?

---

I start by identifying the cardinality of the sample set (omega). It's a circular table so rather than having the normal $6!$ permutations we divide by $6$ it to $5!$. We have three men and three women. Their gender is their only identifying factor so they're interchangeable. This is true for both so we now have $\frac{5!}{3!3!}$.

Here's the problem. When this resolves I get $\frac{10}{3} \approx 3.333$ repeating. What am I doing wrong to end up with a fraction?

Assuming that had resolved as an integer I'd move to find the cardinality of E, our Event. For our event all three woman act as one unit leaving 3 interchangeable men and one group of woman, or 4 objects. It's a circular table so we divide by $4$ and get $3!$. We still have three  Thus we could find the cardinality of E by simplifying $\frac{3!}{3!}=1$.

Comment: Why is "ending up with a fraction" a problem?!?   I have an urn with two white balls and one black ball.  What is the probability you randomly pick the black ball?  In short, *what's the problem*?!?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork They are getting a fractional answer for the cardinality of the sample space.

Answer (score 2):

They are not interchangeable: if the women are $W_1,W_2$, and $W_3$, a seating arrangement in which they sit in the order $W_1W_2W_3$ is distinguishable from one in which they sit in the order $W_2W_1W_3$.

Since the table is circular, we can list any arrangement by starting with $W_1$ and then going around the table clockwise from her. As you say, there are $5!$ ways to fill in the other $5$ people. In order to get the $3$ women seated together, we must have one of the arrangment patterns $W_1WWMMM$, $W_1WMMMW$, or $W_1MMMWW$, where $W$ stands for a woman and $M$ for a man. Thus, there are $3$ pairs of seats in which we can put $W_2$ and $W_3$, and we can seat them in either order. Finally, there are $3!$ possible seating orders for the $3$ men, so there are altogether $3\cdot2\cdot3!=36$ arrangements that have all $3$ women sitting together, and the probability of getting one of them is $\frac{36}{5!}=\frac3{10}$.

Or we can be a little cleverer and realize that if the $3$ women are together, the $3$ men must also be together. The $3$ women can be seated in $3!$ different orders in $3$ consecutive seats, and the $3$ men can then fill the remaining $3$ seats in $3!$ different orders. This yields the same total of $3!\cdot3!=36$ acceptable arrangements and the same probability of $\frac3{10}$ of getting one of them.

Comment: But what if they are interchangeable as the question said? I know these questions don't normally say they're intercahngeble, but is there anything wrong with assuming that they are interchangeable? What if instead of 3 men and 3 women, it was 3 glass plates and 3 plastic plates?

Comment: @JamesA: The question as you stated it does not say that they are interchangeable, and in general people are not unless the contrary is explicitly stated. Moreover, when you count $5!$ possible arrangements altogether, you’re assuming that individual people are distinguishable. If there were $3$ glass and $3$ plastic plates, it might well be reasonable to assume that the glass plates were indistinguishable and likewise the plastic plates. Then there would be exactly one arrangement in which the three glass plates were together, but counting the possible arrangements would be complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Proceeding from $6!$ to $5!$ your essentially fix a place for some person. Therefore the cardinality of the arrangements considering the men and women indistinguishable is
$\frac{5!}{2!3!}=10$. Among these 10 possibilities there are 3 with women (as well as men) sitting together.